# Number of Discontinuities of a Monotone function of several variables

Tags: functions, continuity, compactness

We know that any monotone function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has only countable discontinuities. What about monotone functions on, say  $[a,b]^2 \to [a,b]^2$ (i.e., component-wise monotone)?

1. Do they also have only countable discontinuities ?
2. Does the result hold for mixed monotonic functions ?
3. In general, what happens with the number of discontinuities of monotone functions over ordered compact spaces ?

   Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The function $[0,1]^2\to[0,1]^2$
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(1,1)&\text{if }x+y>1,\\(0,0)&\text{if }x+y\le 1\end{cases}$$
is componentwise monotone increasing (you could even easily make that strictly increasing) and fails to be continuous (even componentwise) in uncountably many points.